# Why python asyncio coroutine is pausing at the line socket.recv(1024) ? why the while loops are failed to cross yeild statements?

Tags: asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine

I have a small application where, one coroutine will send data and the other coroutine will receive data and logs whether it received the exact transmitted data or not.

Both coroutines are in while loops. Some how, the trans() coroutine  and recv() coroutine are not proceeding ahead when they hit the line yield from XXXXXXX

```
data, server = yield from recv_sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

Here is the code

```
import asyncio
import socket
import time
import datetime
import logging

trans_addr = ('localhost', 5555)
recv_addr = ('localhost',6666)

@asyncio.coroutine
def trans():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind(trans_addr)
    i = 0
    global sen_data
    while True:
        print("hi")
        sen_data = "HELLO " + str(i)
        sent = yield from sock.sendto(sen_data.encode(), recv_addr)
        print(sent)
        print("hi1")
        yield from time.sleep(2)
        i += 1
        print("hi1")

@asyncio.coroutine
def recv():
    recv_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    recv_sock.bind(recv_addr)  # binding the receiving end to 1.241 and port 6666
    #recv_sock.setblocking(0)
    while True:
        try:
            print("hello")
            data, server = yield from recv_sock.recvfrom(1024)
            print("hello2")
            if (data):
                recv_data = data.decode()

                if (sen_data == recv_data):
                    logging.info("transmitted data :" + sen_data + " is Received as :" + recv_data + " at :" + str(
                        datetime.datetime.now()) + '\n')
                    print("transmitted data :" + sen_data + " is Received as :" + recv_data + " at :" + str(
                        datetime.datetime.now()) + " from :" + str(server) + '\n')
                else:
                    logging.critical("Data missed : ")
                    logging.critical("Transmitted data " + sen_data + " is != " + "received data : " + recv_data + '\n')
                    print("data is missing--->")
                    print("Transmitted data " + sen_data + " is != " + "received data : " + recv_data + '\n')
        except:
            pass
            # print("not receiving data due to some fault in the receiving socket")
            # time.sleep(1)

loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [loop.create_task(trans()), loop.create_task(recv())]
wait_tasks = asyncio.wait(tasks)
loop.run_forever()
loop.run_until_complete(wait_tasks)
```

Output is:

```
hello
hi
```

Can anyone let me know,why the coroutines are failed to cross the yield from commands? i am using python 3.3.2

Answer (score 2):

`yield from` or `await` should be used with coroutines. `recvfrom` is not a coroutine. For example, you can use  `loop.sock_recv()` instead:

```
reader, writer = socket.socketpair()
writer.setblocking(False)
reader.setblocking(False)
await loop.sock_recv(...)
await loop.sock_sendall(...)
```

Comment: If recvfrom is not a coroutine, then if i want to perform receiving data over a socket as a coroutine - your suggestion is to use loop.sock_recv().           But what if i dont want to pass the loop as a parameter to a coroutine. i couldn't understand, why loop came in to the picture while receiving the data over a socket. can you explain me in detail. i am a newbie for this python world. @Udi

Comment: Please ask this as a new question

Comment: @ringul : since loop is a global variable, you can use it anywhere in your code without passing it as a paramarter.